# Endpoint defined with define-easy-handler returns 404

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

I have defined a simple system in `helloworld.asd`:

```
(asdf:defsystem #:helloworld
  :description "helloworld"
  :author "Duncan Bayne <duncan@bayne.id.au>"
  :license "WTFNMF"
  :depends-on (#:hunchentoot)
  :serial t
  :components ((:file "package")
               (:file "helloworld")))
```

... a package definition in `package.lisp`:

```
(defpackage #:helloworld
  (:use #:cl #:hunchentoot))
```

... and a corresponding hello world webserver in `helloworld.lisp`:

```
(in-package #:helloworld)

(defvar *acceptor* (make-instance 'acceptor :port 4242))

(start *acceptor*)

(define-easy-handler (greet :uri "/hello") ()
  "<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>")
```

In the SLIME REPL I start the web server with:

```
CL-USER> (load "/usr/home/duncan/code/helloworld/helloworld.asd")
CL-USER> (ql:quickload "helloworld")
```

If I navigate to http://localhost:4242/hello, I'd expect to see my hello world HTML.  Instead I get a 404 error, and the log shows:

```
127.0.0.1 - [2017-08-10 08:18:19] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 404 341 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; FreeBSD amd64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
```

I suspect I'm missing something fairly obvious here; any tips / pointers to documentation would be appreciated.  System details are:

```
Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.11 (FreebsdX8664)
FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE amd64
Hunchentoot 1.2.37
Mozilla Firefox 54.0.1
SLIME 20170804.1113
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making an instance of `ACCEPTOR` instead of `EASY-ACCEPTOR` (or a subclass). The easy handler is registered but your acceptor is not going to use it. This should work, for example:

```
(defvar *acceptor* (make-instance 'easy-acceptor :port 4242))
(start *acceptor*)
(define-easy-handler (test :uri "/test") () "Pass")
```

Comment: Thank you :)  I hadn't noticed that there were multiple classes of `ACCEPTOR`.

Comment: @DuncanBayne It happens :-)